# Adding an image to JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, icons, defaulttablemodel

I am wanting to dynamically add data to a JTable including an image. Here is my code:

### Main class

```
        String image = matchedSlots.get(i).getImagePath();
        String title = matchedSlots.get(i).getTitle();
        String director = matchedSlots.get(i).getDirector();
        int rating = matchedSlots.get(i).getRating();
        int runTime = matchedSlots.get(i).getRunningTime();
        searchResults.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new ImageRender(image));

        DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) searchResults.getModel();    
        tm.addRow(new Object[] {image,title,director,rating,runTime});
```

### ImageRenderer Class

```
public class ImageRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

   ImageIcon icon = null;

   public ImageRender(String iconName)
   {
      icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(iconName));
   }  
}
```

This does not work. Only the path name is displayed to the screen. How can I fix this

Comment: Please read about cell renderers in the JTable tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to modify the `TableModel` to return `Icon.class` type for the image column

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...) { 
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class clazz = String.class;
        switch (column) {
            case IMAGE_COLUMN:
                clazz = Icon.class;
                break;
        }
        return clazz;
    }
};
```