# Adding images to each JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, oop, jtable

I have an arraylist of object with the properties Title, Director, Rating, and the pathname for an image. I am wanting dynamically fill the JTable with this data in a for loop as illustrated by the following pseudo-code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < movieCatalog.size(); i++)
{ 
   imageCell = movieCatalog.get(i).getImagePath();
   titleCell = movieCatalog.get(i).getTitle();
   directorCell = movieCatalog.get(i).getDirector();
   ratingCell = movieCatalog.get(i).getRating();
}
```

So for each slot in the arraylist I want to put the data into their respective cells in each row.

How do I put the image into each cell?. I understand that I need to set up an image render but I don't know how to do this. Code for adding data to the table, and the image renderer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched a lot and didn't found an answer and needed to open a new one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222951/java-put-image-in-jtable-cell

Comment: read this: http://pekalicious.com/blog/custom-jpanel-cell-with-jbuttons-in-jtable/

Comment: yes i've been searching alot. I wanted to rewrite my problem in hopes of getting an answer that will actually work.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847271/adding-an-image-to-jtable-cell/16847466#16847466) example

Comment: *Code for adding data to the table, and the image renderer would be much appreciated* To which address do I send my invoice ? There is a whole [`JTable` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) which should allow you to at least add the data to the table

Answer (score 2):

> How do I put the image into each cell?. I understand that I need to
>   set up an image render but I don't know how to do this.

- not required to painting [an image in the Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)
- put [`Icon/ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) to the [`TableModel` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7051005/714968), override [`getColumnClass` with value `Icon/ImageIcon`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13606374/714968)